# Difference between direct putting 2D array values in image and making a pixel from these values and then putting it

Tags: java, awt

I am a beginner in digital image processing field. right now i am coding to get an image from 2D array... i have downloaded these two code samples... when i am using the first one i am getting correct image, but when i am using the second one i am getting processed image with more brightness as compared to the previous one.

Please suggest me what is the difference between these codes and also which code should i refer... i have to use this code to get my research papers results...

1).

```
 public BufferedImage getImage(BufferedImage original, float paddedArray[][], int width, int height) {

        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(width, height, original.getType());
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
                int c = Math.round(paddedArray[i][j]);
                int pixel = c << 16 | c << 8 | c;
                img.setRGB(i, j, pixel);
            }
        }
        return img;
    }
```

---

2).

```
public BufferedImage getImages(BufferedImage original, float paddedArray[][], int width, int height) {

    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(width, height, original.getType());
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) img.getGraphics();
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
            int c = Math.round(paddedArray[i][j]);
            if (c >= greyRange) {
                c = greyRange - 1;
            }
            g.setColor(new Color(c, c, c));
            g.fillRect(i, j, 1, 1);
        }
    }
    return img;
}
```

these codes i am using i only want to know the difference between 
`g.setColor(new Color(c, c, c));` and  `img.setRGB(i, j, pixel);`

Comment: Using floats as color definition and treating them like integers... ? That's interesting... Are you sure that's what you want to do?

Comment: In first case why do you test and set `c` (`c >= greyRange`) when you will never use it again?? Btw ***use a profiler***

Comment: i am using algorithm of local contrast enhancement hence i am using float array. and for case 1. if condition is useless.. i have removed it....

Comment: The float array have values in the range `[0.0, 1.0]` .. I think you should do inverting this way: `c = Math.abs(greyRange - 1.0);`